# Unable to read the xml nodes using final builder

Tags: xml, finalbuilder

Here is the requirement
I want to read all the xml nodes from the xml file and found the last child of each parent node, and include an entry `"Class=Last"` in each last child nodes using finalbuilder (FB6). Here is the xml file structure

```
<HelpTOC>
<HelpTOCNode>
<HelpTOCNode> </HelpTOCNode>
</HelpTOCNode>
</HelpTOC>
```

I have used the `xml iterator` action in final builder to read the nodes and used the Read `XML value to variable` to read the nodes and assign it in the variable and try to found the last child. It reads all the nodes in the xml file and but it returns their Xpath value as below.

```
/HelpTOC/HelpTOCNode[1]/
```

Could you please help me on this ?

How to read all the xml nodes in the xml file and found the last child of each parent. A sample FB project that illustrate the requirement would be more helpful .

Regards

Answer (score 2):

I can help with part of the solution, as I don't recall the XPATH logic for selecting the last node in a collection.

When you define the XML document, include an identifier prefix for the document root node. I use "n".
[image: Final Builder 7 XML Document Definition]

When your working with the various XML nodes, you can then use the following XPATH syntax. Here is an example of an XPath definition for SSRS rdl report definitions.

[image: Final Builder Xpath syntax example]